# Merging specific cells with duplicate ID's in CSV with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

My `.csv` has duplicate clubs throughout the whole file, creating 1500 rows, the reason for this is that each duplicate row is an additional `ClubTDays`, `ClubTStartTime` and `ClubTFinishTime`.

Meaning rather than write the club times in one cell, it has been exported with each new class duplicating the rest of the information.

This `.csv.` is imported into Wordpress using All Import, then the clubs are shown on a google map with the right information.

My issue is that it can say the same address 8-9 times because of the day/times over rows.

### Question:

The `ClubNumber` is the `id` of the club. Is there a way with php to merge rows with the same `ClubNumber`, keep the address the same for these duplicates, but for the `ClubTDays` / `ClubTStartTime`/`ClubTFinishTime` differenciate, they're combined into one cell.

This way, the google map will only list the one address per club, but list several days that they opperate.

---

Here's some example code i'm working with:

```
$handle = fopen("CLUBEXP.csv", "r");

$row = 0;
$ClubNumberList = array();

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $ClubNumber = $data[0];
    $ClubTDays = $data[19];

    if ( array_key_exists($ClubNumber, $ClubNumberList) ) {
        $ClubNumberList[$ClubNumber][] = $ClubTDays;
    } else {
        $ClubNumberList[$ClubNumber] = array($ClubTDays);
    }
    $row++;
}

print_r( $ClubNumberList );
```

The issue with this code is that it removes all over columns. It merges the day fine, but it doesn't copy over the rest.

Once these fields have been merged, I need to save the `.csv` with a different name like "clubs-merged.csv" so I can import it through wordpress.

Can this be done? & Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: It removes all the columns apart from `ClubNumber` and `ClubTDays`. I don't want that to happen at all. I need all columns, i just don't need 6 of the same address